# Open Source Interpolation Service?

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, mapserver, open-source-gis, interpolation

We are seeking an open source solution for dynamic (on the fly) IDW or Kriging points interpolation.

Basically we are looking for something similar to [ArcGIS Spatial Analysis Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/analysis/api-reference/interpolate-points.htm).

[image]

Interpolation can be performed in the browser or on the server side.

Comment: Could is be something close to rendering transformations of GeoServer http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html or density maps in MapServer http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-108.html. Sorry that I do not know much about interpolation theory. You can also suggest modifications for the developers if current implementations are not like what you want.

Comment: Surface Interpolation in GeoServer http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/08/surface-interpolation-in-geoserver/

Answer (score 4):

How about using [GDAL_Grid?](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) Just pass the arguments over to GDAL and return the raster file or render it in the web browser.

It does IDW, Nearest neighbor, and averaging and has a robust set of input parameters.

Comment: nice I didn't know GDAL had interpolators!!!

Comment: I just started using them myself. FAST!

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a Web Processing Service (WPS) with Zoo-project.org and GRASS GIS. For pointers, see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation - "Reinterpolation of 'sparse' (scattered points or lines) maps" and also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WPS.
QGIS offers a WPS client which you can then run to use your WPS interpolation service.